# ResultSet is getting closed on executing statement.execute(sql)

Tags: resultset

On executing the follwing code i am getting error java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed

public class SavePoints {

```
public void extract(ResultSet rs)
{
     int c;
    try {
        while(rs.next())
        {
        c = rs.getInt("id");
       String d=rs.getString("name");
       String e=rs.getString("city");
       String f=rs.getString("state");
       String g=rs.getString("country");

    //Displaying values
     System.out.println("ID is:"+c+"\tName is:"+d+"\tCity is:"+e+"\tState is:"+f+"\tCountry is:"+g);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SavePoints spobj=new SavePoints();
    try {
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Divya", "SYSTEM", "tiger");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from publishers");
        spobj.extract(rs);
        //DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = con.getMetaData();
        //System.out.println(databaseMetaData.getDriverMajorVersion());
        //Savepoint sp=con.setSavepoint("Deleting Rows");
        st.execute("delete from publishers where id=104");
        //con.rollback(sp);
        spobj.extract(rs);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

What is the error? I cannot find it. Please let me know. I am a newbie.. so please explain in simple terms. I am grateful for your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you have called  s`pobj.extract(rs);` twice ,

first time when this function executes resultset moves to last because you are using `rs.next()`..

to achieve this you have use scrollable resultset

```
Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

and for next call of `spobj.extract(rs);` reverse the call of resultset by `rs.previous()`

Comment: Just a friendly hint: there are some formatting options on top of the answer box: if you use, for instance, the `{}` button, it formats your code (monospaced font, breaks work). This will help readability for lines of code (and especially blocks of those) in your anwers :)